# Multiple authentication types in Django App

Tags: django

I have a Django App which exposes some REST APIs, with LDAP authentication enabled. It is working fine.

Now, I want this app to support OKTA authentication as well so that Web UI client can authenticate via OKTA, not through LDAP.

How can I configure my Django project to support both kinds of authentication (Ldap + Okta)?

Comment: Did you try to integrate https://github.com/fangli/django-saml2-auth ?

Comment: I saw this lib. But, my question is how can I integrate both authentication providers in one app?